# Derivative of the $p$-Schatten norm of a symmetric matrix, raised to the $p$th power.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Given a symmetric matrix $S$, I would like to calculate the derivative of the $p$-Schatten norm of $S$ raised to the $p$th power i.e. $\frac{\partial\|S\|_p^p}{\partial S}$ where $\|S\|_p$ is the $p$-Schatten norm of $S$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\G{\operatorname{sign}}
\def\S{\operatorname{sym}}
\def\T{\operatorname{tr}}
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$First, solve the more general problem where $S$ is a rectangular matrix. Then, in the final step, allow it to be a (square) symmetric matrix.

Define an auxiliary matrix $A$ such that
$$\eqalign{
A &= \l(S^TS\r)^{1/2} \quad&\implies\quad A=A^T = \S(A) \\
A\,A &= S^TS &\implies\quad \S(A\;dA) = \S(S^TdS) \\
}$$
This matrix allows the Schatten $p$-Norm to be written as
$$\eqalign{
\sigma &= \|S\|_p = \Big[\T\l(A^p\r)\Big]^{1/p} \\
}$$
Now calculate the differential and gradient of the $p^{th}$ power of the norm.
$$\eqalign{
\sigma^p &= \T\l(A^p\r) \\
d\sigma^p &= pA^{p-1}:dA \\
 &= \S(pA^{p-2}):A\,dA \\
 &= pA^{p-2}:\S(A\,dA) \\
 &= pA^{p-2}:\S(S^TdS) \\
 &= pSA^{p-2}:dS \\
\g{\sigma^p}{S} &= pSA^{p-2} \\
}$$
People are usually more interested in the gradient of the norm (not raised to any power)
$$\eqalign{
\g{\sigma^p}{S} &= p\sigma^{p-1}\,\g{\sigma}{S} \\
\g{\sigma}{S} &= \l(\frac{S}{\sigma}\r) \! \l(\frac{A}{\sigma}\r)^{p-2} \\\\
}$$

---

In the above a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \;=\; \T(AB^T) \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
The `sym()` operator is defined as
$$\S(S) = \tfrac 12\l(S+S^T\r)$$
and it has a nice property with respect to the Frobenius product
$$\S(A):B \;=\; A:\S(B)\\$$

---

Finally, if $S$ is symmetric, then
$$\eqalign{
A &= \l(S^2\r)^{1/2} = \G(S)\;S \\
}$$
where `sign()` is the [Matrix Sign](https://nhigham.com/2020/12/15/what-is-the-matrix-sign-function/) function.

Since the sign function is involutory, when $p$ is *even* all the signs cancel, i.e.
$$\G\!\l(S\r)^{p-2} = I \qquad\implies\quad A^{p-2} = S^{p-2}$$
and one can simply replace
$\,S\to A\;$  in the gradient formula to obtain
$$\eqalign{
\g{\sigma^p}{S} &= pS^{p-1} \\
}$$
However, when $p$ is *odd* one of the sign functions does not cancel and the gradient becomes
$$\eqalign{
\g{\sigma^p}{S} &= pS^{p-1} \G(S) \\
}$$
**NB:**$\;$ If the matrix $S$ is **also** semi-positive definite, then
$$\G(S)=I \quad\implies\quad A=S$$
and the sign issue goes away.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. I don't suppose you have any links that go through matrix calculus in detail? @greg

Comment: @mrjoeybux The current site is a pretty good resource, just poke around. [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf) is a useful free reference. If you want to buy a book, my favorite is Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_  although the standard text is probably Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_ $\quad$